# swift 3 json serialisation

Tags: ios, json, swift, serialization, swift3

I'm trying to serialize a JSON using Swift 3, and coming up short..
This is the JSON (summarised):

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "a": {
        "b": "1",
        "c": {
          "d": 0.0
        }
      },
      "wantThisOne": "2016-10-07T08:47:00Z"
    },
    {
      "a": {
        "b": "1",
        "c": {
          "d": 0.0
        }
      },
      "notThisOne": "2016-10-07T09:05:00Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where I want the date from 'wantThisOne', but not sure how exactly to get it...
This is as far as I get but nothing i try in the if let block seems to work for me... anyone dealt with something like this? I've had a look through stack overflow etc... but super stuck.

```
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1 as URLRequest, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: URLResponse?, data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                print(jsonResult)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in Swift use generic type `Dictionary` like `[String:Any]` instead of `NSDictionary` and after you get dictionary get the array from the `value` key and iterate through the Array and get the `wantThisOne` from every object.

```
if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
     if let valueArray = jsonResult["values"] as? [[String:Any]] {
          for item in valueArray {
              print("Date - \(item["wantThisOne"])")
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: @Richie Welcome mate :)